# INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session

Tags: apex, c#, login-errors, partner

I am integrating salesforce in my asp.net application. I am using partner WSDL from my account lets say I am having a developer account XYZ@gmail.com and I have downloaded partner WSDl from that account and integrate it and now I am trying to login from some other credentials like ABC@gmail.com. Now I am getting an exception

> "INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader:
>   Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key:
>   00DG0000000l7dV!ASAAQHNyaM8cop7Oy2pgqjdCQxb4Vwim1BsEvNDYi7Qy45NhEIzg83Mvo2lAMFi37ycpcNKl.vntNgztNRQqFMxZB87cxJLx"

if I am doing so. I have found that the URL of developer ID is like na15.salesforce.com and the credentials that I am using having URL as na11.salesforce.com. So will it create any issue and I am able to login through the credentials but when I am making any request then I am getting an exception. Kindly check the below code for login part

```
 LoginResult lr = binding.login(username, password);                
 String authEndPoint = binding.Url;
 binding.Url = lr.serverUrl;
 binding.SessionHeaderValue = new PartnerWSDL.SessionHeader();
 binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;
 header = new PartnerWSDL.SessionHeader();
 header.sessionId = lr.sessionId;
 printUserInfo(lr, lr.serverUrl);
 done = true;
```

Above part is working fine but when I running below code then it generates the exception

```
InsertUserService service = new InsertUserService();
service.SessionHeaderValue = new SForce.SessionHeader();
service.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId;
SForce.Account account = new SForce.Account();
account.Id = "001G000001DJv6n";
String strs = service.InsertLead(new SForce.Lead() { });
```

Here InsertUser is the class declared in APEX code. So can any one please suggest me is there any issue in my code or I following wrong path.

Comment: In your second code you are not setting the Url to the serverUrl, so the request is going to the wrong place, and it doesn't know about your sessionId, hence the error.

Comment: I have trying that too but If I am doing service.Url = binding.Url in my second code then I am getting below exception "No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/SCHE_DULE_ONCE/InsertUser}InsertLead". My binding URL is "https://na11.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0/00DG0000000l7dV" and then the srevice URL is "https://na15.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/SCHE_DULE_ONCE/InsertUser" so how can I change the URL as both are looking different.

Comment: for custom services you need to combine the original path with the hostname from the login result for the new url.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still getting the exception "No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/SCHE_DULE_ONCE/InsertUser}InsertLead". I am getting the binding URL as "https://na11.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0/00DG0000000l7dV" and service URL as "https://na15.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/SCHE_DULE_ONCE/InsertUser" so what should I do, currently i have assigned the Binding URL to server URL but getting the above error. Please help me in this regards. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To handle this issue, add an exception handler and relogin to salesforce. That should fix it. There seems no solution or setting to address this.